# How to add a startup program on all users of an AD OU

Tags: windows, active-directory, group-policy

I want to add a startup program on all the users of a specific OU. The aim is to have the same comportement as if I use the Environment tab of each users. (I juste want my program and not the explorer)

Thanks!

Comment: The way to word the question is:  "How do I assign a logon script to users using a GPO?"  The answer is, "Look it up online using the language I provided."

Comment: Thank you, but it's not what I'm looking for, I want to know if it's possible to have this : http://www.chicagotech.net/images/ts2.gif on a group or on a OU. with a logon script, I will still have explorer and the other statup program lauched

Comment: Dude, Were not in 1995. Use GPO.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe the easiest way using GPO. Create a Group Policy to create a Scheduled Task configured to run on User logon. On the Security Options, set the user as `%LogonDomain%\%LogonUser%` and tick to run when the user is connected. Scheduled Tasks never betrays you.

Configure the Scheduled Task on the User hierarchy: 
`User Configuration/Preferences/Control Panel Settings/Scheduled Tasks`

Set the action to Start a program.

Set the security option to run as `%LogonDomain%\%LogonUser%`.

[image: print image]

Set the trigger option to run on specific user logon.

[image: print image]

Comment: This will write the actual username in the scheduled task when the task is created and therefore only run with this user in the future. I really hate this - why is it not using the variable and it would be OK. I did not really have a fix - maybe only set the task to REPLACE then it will be written again.